# Resque remote jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

So I have two servers.

Server A: Has redis, ruby + resque gem + rake gem
Server B: Has ruby on rails + resque gem

From Server B I enqueue a Job to Redis on Server A. Server A receives the job:

```
*** Found job on test
*** got: (Job{test} | TestQueue | [])
*** Running before_fork hooks with [(Job{test} | TestQueue | [])]
*** resque-1.23.1: Forked 10388 at 1362750385
*** Failed to start worker : #<NameError: uninitialized constant TestQueue>
```

So I figured the jobs need to live on Server A. So I moved the jobs there. But then, when i enqueue from Server B I get the following:

```
rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
irb(main):001:0>  Resque.enqueue(TestQueue)
NameError: uninitialized constant TestQueue
```

The only way I did get it to work was when I had the job at both servers, but thats far from ideal.

How can I get around queueing jobs remotely?

Comment: Where is the TestQueue class define in Server A and Server B

Answer (score 0):

`resque-remote` is a gem used to remote enqueue jobs.

If `Resque.inline` is true, the job will be enqueued to your current queue.

Source: https://github.com/localshred/resque-remote

Comment: For anyone reading this, if you are using new versions of Resque, ie >= 2.x, you don't need this gem. Just use the standard API method Resque.push instead. http://rubydoc.info/github/resque/resque/Resque:push